# ByteArray to HttpResponse

Tags: android, parsing, http, httpresponse

I've a server and a client. My server sends a HttpResponse in a text format. I'm able to receive the text at client. I need to convert back the text to HttpResponse object. Are there any opensource libraries or in-built java/Android mechanisms to do this?

All I've got is converting HttpResponse to text.

Comment: How do you receive the byteArray?

Comment: using recv system call.

Comment: `My server sends a HttpResponse in a byteArray`. A http server is a http server and as such will send just text, pictures or docs. It is just always a stream of bytes. So i wonder what you mean by a response as byte array.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry my mistake. I've edited the question.

Comment: `I need to convert back the text to HttpResponse object` ??? What do you mean? And why would you? For what? It will never have been a response object before. Why do you think you need something? What do you want to do with the received text?

Comment: What do you want to do with the received text?

I'll read the header, data and other information from the text I receive. As it is a simple text now I could not parse it efficiently, Thats why I need a HttpParser. I guess this answers all the questions.

Comment: If it is a html text you can use an xml parser like JSOUP.

Comment: Its not an HTML, Its a kind of

    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Length: 100"

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
response.getEntity().writeTo(baos);
byte[] bytes = baos.getBytes();
```

Then you could add the content to another `HttpResponse` object as follows:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
response.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(bytes));
```

Comment: Basically I need a HttpParser open source library.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this using Apache Commons IO: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

```
private byte[] receiveByteArrayData(HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection)
    throws IOException
{
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
}
```

Sending `byte[]` data:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://your.url.here:yourPortNumber/something");
    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpUrlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);

    httpUrlConnection.connect();

    httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
    httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream().flush();
    if (httpsUrlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) //OK
    {
        System.out.println("successfully uploaded data");
    }
    httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly what I want from 
[parse http response bytes in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549951/parse-http-response-bytes-in-java)

Thanks everyone for responses :)